# Finding Initial state vector with given values

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

I am not sure how to use a given values to form a initial state vector.

There are 30% of customers from Company A switch to company B every month, and 35% customers from Company B switch to company A every month.

From the information above, the stochastic matrix is:

$$S=\begin{pmatrix}0.7&0.35\\ 0.3&0.65\end{pmatrix}$$

If I know that the start of year when Company A has 250,000 customer and Company B has 125,000, how can I write an initial state vector x0 ?

Do I just simply put these 2 value together to form a state vector ? if not is there any formula to calculate the initial state vector ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Markov chains deal with probability the entries of the initial state vector $x^0$ should sum to $1$. So, this is just the proportions of customers from company $A$ and $B$.

$x^0: \begin{pmatrix}
2/3\\
1/3
\end{pmatrix}$

I believe the transition probability matrix you have should be 
$$\begin{matrix}
&A&B\\
A&.7&.3\\
B&.35&.65
\end{matrix}$$

because the rows of the transition probability matrix should sum to $1$ (since the total probability of moving from state $A$ to state $A$ and $A$ to $B$ should be $1$).

An easy way to read the transition probability matrix is by looking at the row, let's say company $A$, and the probability that the customer will switch from $A$ to $B$ in the next month is $.3$